# Dash Layout: How resize borders

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a Dash app and I want to display multiple graphs in a card deck layout with two cards in each row. Additionally, I want to set a larger width for the cards, but due to the width, the cards are not staying in two columns as expected.

Here's the current layout code I have:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dropdown',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in years],
                    value=years[0],
                    className="form-control"
                ),
                dcc.Graph(
                    id='graph1',
                    figure=fig1,
                    className="card shadow"
                )
            ], width=8),
            dbc.Col([
                html.Div(style={'padding': 30}),
                dcc.Graph(
                    id='graph2',
                    figure=fig2,
                    className="card shadow",
                    style={'padding-left': '50px'}
                )
            ], width=8)
        ], className='card-deck'),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([html.Br(),
                     dcc.Graph(
                         id='graph3',
                         figure=fig3,
                         className="card shadow"
                     )
                     ], width=8),
            #  dbc.Col([html.Br(),
            #      dcc.Graph(
            #          id='graph4',
            #          figure=fig4,
            #          className="card shadow",
            #          style={'padding-left': '50px'}
            #      )
            #  ], width=8)
        ], className='card-deck')
    ], className='container mt-5')
])
```

(temporaly I have not assigned graph 4)

I tried adding mb-4 Bootstrap class to the dbc.Col components, but it didn't solve the issue. I want the cards to maintain their larger width while displaying two cards in each row and stacking appropriately on smaller screens.

Is there a way to achieve this using CSS Flexbox or Bootstrap classes? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Desired output:
[image]

Actual output:
[image]